# Magento2: How to delete cookies programmatically?

Tags: magento2, login, cookie

I want to delete cookies programmatically before as login customer.

Comment: Above url will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overview of using cookie in Magento 2
Step 1: Create a controller to read cookie
Step 2: Create a controller to delete cookie
Step 1: Create a controller to read cookie
The first is setting a Readcookie.php controller in the `app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Cookie`. The Readcookie.php contains the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Cookie;
class Readcookie extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
*/
protected $_cookieManager;
/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
*/
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
)
{
     $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
     parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
     $cookieValue = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie(\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Cookie\Addcookie::COOKIE_NAME);
     echo($cookieValue);
}
}
```

Step 2: Create a controller to delete cookie
Create the Deletecookie controller in the `app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Cookie` with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Cookie;
class Deletecookie extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
*/
protected $_cookieManager;
/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
*/
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
)
{
     $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
     parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
     $this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie(
         \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Cookie\Addcookie::COOKIE_NAME
     );
     echo('DELETED');
}
}
```

And now, you can enable the cookie on your Magento 2 store. If you have any trouble in tracking the topic, leave a comment to ask for the help. Good luck to you!

Comment: I will check and update you soon.

Comment: I can't understand this line $cookieValue = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie(\Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Cookie\Addcookie::COOKIE_NAME);

Comment: That line is simply saying: look for the PHP constant called COOKIE_NAME inside the class \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Cookie\Addcookie and retrieve the constant value (which would contain the name of the cookie).

Comment: You may check more details from the artcile https://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/magento2-get-set-delete-cookie/ and from magento core class as well https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreCookieManager.php#L77

Answer (score 2):

The short answer could look like this.

```
if ($this->_cookieManager->getCookie('recently_viewed_product')) {
    $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory->createCookieMetadata()
        ->setPath($this->_sessionManager->getCookiePath());

    $this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie('recently_viewed_product', $metadata);
}
```

Be sure to include the following interfaces, factories and etc.

```
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;

....

protected $_sessionManager;
protected $_cookieMetadataFactory;
protected $_cookieManager;

....

public function __construct(
    ....
    Context $context,
    SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager,
    CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
) {
    $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->_cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;

    parent::__construct($context);
}
```